# recursively set 777 permissions in java without using NIO

Tags: java, permissions, 777

Is there a way to set 777 permissions on a path recursively(so that all directories on the path get 777 permissions) without using NIO.

We can do it for the last leaf of a given file by methods in the file class like below

```
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;


public class permissionTest {

    public static void main(String [] args){
        String dir = "./leaf1/leaf2/leaf3";

        File baseDir = new File(dir);

        boolean success = baseDir.mkdirs();
        if (success) {
            System.out.println("Created dirs");
            baseDir.setExecutable(true, false);
            baseDir.setReadable(true, false);
            baseDir.setWritable(true, false);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Not created");
        }

    }

}
```

the above gives 777 to leaf3 , how to give 777 to leaf1 & leaf2 as well? In a single command?

Comment: What's the reason why you don't want to set the permissions using multiple commands?

Comment: there should be a better way like chmod -R:) , also not great to do it for deeply nested paths

Comment: You want to give 777 to the current and 2 previous parent ? It is usually the other way around, apply 777 to the parent directory and all his childs

Comment: if i give 777 to leaf1 in example above , leaf2 and leaf3 won't get it

Comment: Why the artificial restriction to not use NIO?

Comment: Is it possible to do it in a very few steps using NIO?

Comment: You haven't answered my question.

Comment: Also, I have a legacy component running on Java 6, can't switch to java7 just for this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 -R ./leaf1");
            p.waitFor();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: This could give "collateral damage" too: it might also set permissions on folders that you don't want to change.

Comment: yep, and i was looking for a java based approach...not using chmod. i think this approach is slower

Comment: @Bartvbi It is exactly what the OP asked for: "all directories on the path get 777 permissions".

Comment: @nikel Slower than what?